# How to check inside dll that some library referenced in project where that library used?

Tags: c#, dll, dll-reference

Is there a way to check that some library (assume dll) referenced in project.

Example

```
public void SomeFunction()
    if(libraryReferenced){
    //
    }
}
```

And in outer project
//Library not Referenced

```
MyDll.SomeFunction();
```

In my dll function // libraryReferenced = false

and vice versa

Thanks.

Comment: Please could you clarify why you want to do this, as it may affect the proposed answers.

Comment: I am trying make a collection of most used Extensions . Some of them possible when That library referneced.